# Save plots from loop over datetime object

Tags: r, loops, plot, datetime-format

I get this error message when automatically saving plots so often that I've put together a very simple example based on [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/automatically-save-your-plots-to-a-folder/) code to illustrate my frustation.

This is the code based on the example, which obviously works:

```
names <- LETTERS[1:5] 

for(i in seq_along(names)){
  x <- rnorm(10, 5, 1)
  y <- seq(1:10)

  mypath <- file.path("YOUR_FILE_PATH",paste("myplot_", names[i], ".tiff", sep = ""))

  tiff(file=mypath)
  mytitle <- paste("my title is", names[i])
  plot(x,y, main = mytitle)
  dev.off()
}
```

Now substitute the character string in `names` for a `POSIXlt` object:

```
    dates <- c("2015-04-27 14:30:00","2015-04-27 18:15:00",
               "2015-04-27 22:30:00","2015-04-27 22:45:00",
               "2015-04-27 23:00:00")
    dates <- as.data.frame(dates)
    dates <- strptime(dates$dates,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    for(i in seq_along(dates)){
      x <- rnorm(10, 5, 1)
      y <- seq(1:10)

      mypath <- file.path("YOUR_FILE_PATH",paste("myplot_", dates[i], ".tiff", sep = ""))

      tiff(file=mypath)
      mytitle <- paste("my title is", dates[i])
      plot(x,y, main = mytitle)
      dev.off()
    }
```

Then I get a popup window saying "FILEPATH/myplot_2015-04-27 14:30:00.tiff: cannot open" and R will give my the following error message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In dev.off() :
  unable to open TIFF file 'FILEPATH/myplot_2015-04-27 14:30:00.tiff'
```

Ok, so R doesn't seem to like the `POSIXlt` object. Let try just printing the plots:

```
for(i in seq_along(dates)){
  x = rnorm(10, 5, 1)
  y = seq(1:10)

  mytitle = paste("my title is", dates[i])
  print(plot(x,y, main = mytitle))
}
```

This works, at least after restarting R, as it still for some reason wants to print the plots to the filepath specified earlier. So the problem is not the format, but the saving to file. Can someone explain this to me, please?

Comment: Depending on the filesystem you work on spaces in the filename could be a problem, try specifying a date format that does not contain spaces and other special characters, for example with `strftime`.

Comment: at least on my Windows, the `:` is not allowed in filenames.

Comment: Thanks a million - that worked. Feel a bit silly for not thinking of that myself...

Comment: @DaveTurek is right , `:` is part of forbidden character , member of this [list of forbidden characters in windows file path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247). I would suggest replacing `:` with `_` and reconstruct date-time later

Comment: I prefer something like: ``gsub(":", ".", gsub(" ", "_", dates))`` as 'blank' can cause problems with some console programs.